# Python time.sleep() being ignored in timer program

Tags: python, sleep

I have been trying to create an extremely simple timer program for the past few days.
However, I have come across a major roadblock, in which the second delay countdown is just completely ignored when running the program.
I have tried replacing time.sleep(1) with time.sleep(1000), rearranging it all over the while loop it is in, but to no avail. The program just runs, with no delay neither in the beginning nor during the loop.

```
import time
hour, minute, second = 1, 2, 10

print("Starting now.")
x = 1
while x < 2:
    print(str(hour) + ":" + str(minute) + ":" + str(second)) 
    time.sleep(1)
    second = second - 1
    if second == 0:
        minute = minute - 1
        second = second + 60
        if minute ==0:
            hour = hour - 1
            minute = minute + 60
            if hour == 0:
                x = x + 1
```

It would be a great help if someone could figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: I replaced your input requirement with a self-contained, hard-coded example.

Comment: Either way, the problem doesn't appear for me; I get very nice 1-second delays, as expected.  Your time-computing logic is wrong, however.  This would be more reliable if you use the `datetime` module.

Comment: your code works fine for me. I tried time.sleep(1) and time.sleep(5). It seems to work perfectly.

Comment: You can probably try monotonic in python 2 or time.monotonic in python 3. It is said to have better performance in some cases.

Comment: @prune That's really strange. I've been getting outputs with no delay at all. Is there possibly a problem with my IDE?

Comment: @AidenHong  Yes, that's my worry: that the problem is in your development environment.  You might check the documentation to see whether `sleep` is properly supported.  I'll be quite annoyed with those developers if it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have commented the code as given in original question does correctly sleep in a properly configured environment, this answer addresses the logic issue in the time handling by using datetime. The timedelta from subtracting two datetimes does not provide hours and minutes so these are calculated from the seconds.

```
import time, datetime,math

d = datetime.timedelta(hours=1,minutes=2,seconds=10)
endtime = (datetime.datetime.now()+ d)

    print("Starting now.")
    while datetime.datetime.now().time() <endtime.time():
        td = endtime - datetime.datetime.now()
        print(str(math.floor(td.seconds / 3600)) + ":" +
              str(math.floor(td.seconds / 60) - math.floor(td.seconds / 3600)*60 ) + ":" +
              str(td.seconds - math.floor(td.seconds / 60)*60) ) 
        time.sleep(1)
```

You can also correct the logic in the original in the following manner

```
import time
hour, minute, second = 1, 2, 10

print("Starting now.")
x = 1
while x < 2:
    print(str(hour) + ":" + str(minute) + ":" + str(second)) 
    time.sleep(1)
    second = second - 1
    if second < 0:
        minute = minute - 1
        if minute >= -1:
            second = second + 60      
        if minute < 0:
            hour = hour - 1
            if hour >= 0:
                minute = minute + 60
    if hour <= 0 and minute <= 0 and second <= 0:
        x = x + 1
```